# NSTimer to control a series of events

Tags: ios, nstimer

Can NSTimer be used to fire a series of events. For instance for effect:

Its kick off Click start to toss
create random number
wait 5 seconds show result
wait 3 seconds start the match?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to repeat at a given interval, but not a variable one. If you really wanted to wait 5 seconds and then then wait another 3 seconds you'd probably want to chain timers. So, when the first timer fires and calls a message, that message creates a second timer with a different time interval.

Comment: That was what I figured I would have to do. Thanks.

Comment: I am using a series of these:

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(partOne:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a case where the [Prototype Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) would apply: make an NSTimer and set it up with all the properties you want, and then clone that object each time you need to make another. Or you could just make a factory. Objective C does not have a clone, but the NSCoding protocol is actually a workable and proper way of doing cloning (unlike Java's broken (and abandoned) clone interface).